# A well known Property of a Mollifier?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let me denote by $\rho_{n}(x)=n \rho(nx)$ where $\rho$ is any positive smooth compactly supported function (let say in $[-2,2]$) whose integral over $\mathbb R$ is equal to 1. Does anyone see why necessary,  for any $\delta>0$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\vert y \vert > \delta} \rho_{n} (y) \ dy = 0 ?
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your $[-2,2]$ for the support of $\rho$, you have that $\rho_n(x)=0$ whenever $|x|\geq2/n$. So, if $n$ is big enough so that $\delta>2/n$ (i.e. $n>2/\delta$), $\rho_n(x)=0$ for $|x|>\delta$. In other words, for $n>2/\delta$ we have
$$
\int_{|y|>\delta}\rho_n(y)dy=0. 
$$

Comment: Yes - I agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you want to approximate [the Delta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html).

Comment: I mean, how to prove that...

Comment: try to take $\rho_{n}-\delta$ and find its convolution with $f$.

Comment: it is equal to $\int_{\mathbb R} (\rho_{n}(y)-\delta) f(x-y) \ dy$

Comment: So the part around $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$'s integration would give us $0$. Assuming for the moment $p_{n}(y)>0$ for all $y$. The rest of the integral $\int p_{n}(y)f(x-y)dy$ might not approach $0$ for a suitable chosen $f(x)$. I think the general case is similar.

Comment: I think that it suffices to choose $n$ sufficiently big (which is allowed due to the limit) so that we are outside the support and the integral is $0$ (actually, one can take $n \geq \frac{1}{\delta}$  (with $\delta$ as big as we please, and since $\vert y \vert > \delta$ the product $\vert n y \vert >1$ making the integral equal to $0$. Isn't it?

Comment: You can choose $n=100^{100}$ if you like. But I do not think this would make the part off origin's integral vanish. Your assumption is $\int_{\epsilon}p_{n}(y)dy+\int^{-\epsilon}p_{n}(y)dy$ does not vanish. Then I can assume it is constant(say 1) and choose $f$ accordingly.

Comment: Oupss... sorry I forgot to mention that f is continuous thus the part near the origin is small.

Comment: This is of no consequence, you are concerning about the part off the origin at here. I do not understand why you mention this "fact". Also $f$ is arbitrary.

Comment: It important since the $\delta$ comes from the continuity property of $f$ and it can be chosen as small as we want, in particular we have to choose it so that the concerned integral is equal to $0$.

Comment: No, $f$ can be any $L^{1}$ function you like, and $f$ does not need to be continuous. But $p_{n}$ you are constructing need to be smooth. I think this is your confusion.